# "uses of target_link_libraries must be either all-keyword or all-plain"

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm

I managed to build llvm and clang and now I am trying to create a ClangTool according to [clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html#step-1-create-a-clangtool). But I am getting the following error when I am trying to build it:

```
CMake Error at tools/clang/tools/loop-convert/CMakeLists.txt:6 (target_link_libraries):
  The keyword signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with 
  the target "loop-convert".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a target
  must be either all-keyword or all-plain.

  The uses of the keyword signature are here:

    * cmake/modules/LLVM-Config.cmake:105 (target_link_libraries)
    * cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:771 (target_link_libraries)
```

My current CMakeLists.txt is:

```
set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS support)

add_clang_executable(loop-convert
  LoopConvert.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(loop-convert
  clangTooling
  clangBasic
  clangASTMatchers
)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use keyword signature of `target_link_libraries`; effectively, you need to add `PRIVATE` to the `target_link_libraries` statement in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(loop-convert PRIVATE
  clangTooling
  clangBasic
  clangASTMatchers
)
```

This is because `add_llvm_executable` uses such signature and you can't mix them in CMake.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused. I updated the question with my CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I was confused too. I've updated my answer, try that.

Comment: I was stuck on a similar problem with a custom version of clang. I added the `PRIVATE` keyword for each `target_link_libraries` on CMakeFiles.txt's with problems and worked

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, CMake should have just printed a pedantic warning rather than hard-breaking the API people have been relying on.
The following code makes the function backward-compatible, while still allowing the newer signature to be used.
It prints a warning to remind you to upgrade your code.

```
function(target_link_libraries target)
    if(ARGV1 MATCHES "^(PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE)$")
        _target_link_libraries(${target} ${ARGN})
    else()
        _target_link_libraries(${target} PUBLIC ${ARGN})
        message(AUTHOR_WARNING "target_link_libraries: missing PRIVATE, PUBLIC or INTERFACE for target ${target}. Defaulting to PUBLIC.")
    endif()
endfunction()
```

Comment: There is no "hard-breaking the API". It is perfectly allowed to use `target_link_libraries` without a keyword (PUBLIC/PRIVATE/INTERFACE) and CMake won't warn about that. But mixing keyword and non-keyword calls to `target_link_libraries` for a single target was never allowed. Also, a non-keyword call is NOT strictly equivalent to PUBLIC keyword: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396608/what-is-default-target-link-libraries-privacy-setting. (In many aspects non-keyword and PUBLIC keyword behaves similarly. But for backward compatibility non-keyword has specifics in complex cases.)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification as to when exactly the problem starts to occur. So, my wrapper only works most of the time, but there's no guarantee that it's bug-for-bug compatible with older cmake scripts :/