# What is default target_link_libraries privacy setting?

Tags: c++, cmake

I wonder what is the default `target_link_libraries` privacy.

I added line in CMake:

```
target_link_libraries(myTarget
        libraryA
        libraryB
        )
```

But I don't know if it is `PRIVATE` or `PUBLIC` or maybe `INTERFACE`.
I check [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html#id3), but I don't see answer for my question :(

Edit:

I found [sth](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-May/063400.html):

> As a final note, if you call target_link_libraries() and do not
>   specify any of PRIVATE, PUBLIC or INTERFACE, you may be tempted to
>   believe that it will be treated as PUBLIC. The situation is actually
>   more complicated than that though. It may be treated as PUBLIC or
>   PRIVATE, depending on what other target_link_library() calls and/or
>   target property manipulations have been performed. The documentation
>   for target_link_libraries() talks a bit about this, but you have to go
>   digging into the documentation for the target properties it mentions
>   to get an understanding of what circumstances lead to PRIVATE or
>   PUBLIC behaviour.

What circumstances? *(BTW. Author of this words is Craig Scott that seems to be active user of SO, I belive he can answer to me...)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Description of [policy 0023](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/policy/CMP0023.html) suggests, that there is **no "default" behavior** of `target_link_libraries` - every single project should have calls to this command either all-keyworded or none-keyworded:

> Plain and keyword target_link_libraries signatures cannot be mixed.

Comment: "certainly one is carried out..." - Default linking has **no direct equivalent** in `PUBLIC`, `PRIVATE` and `INTERFACE` area. Would you use only `target_link_libraries` calls, they call will have both immediate and transitive effects, like `PUBLIC`. But for some other commands and accessing properties transitive effect could be lost, so behavior would be similar like `PRIVATE`.

Comment: CMake tends to not break the old (legacy) code. So would you use only functions existed in old CMake (say, up to version ~2.8), you may expect these functions to work even in newer CMake interpretator. But would you mix old functions with the new ("modern") ones, weird things could happen.

Comment: But why is there no direct equivalent? Do you mean we cannot achieve the same behavior `target_link_libraries(mylib A)` by writing the keyword version like `target_link_libraries(mylib <PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE> A)`?

Comment: @IgNite: Yes, using keywords you cannot achieve **exactly** same behavior as without keyword.