# What is the default privacy/scope setting for include_directories?

Tags: cmake, scope, dependencies, include

I understand that `target_include_directories()` can be used in conjunction with `PUBLIC`, `INTERFACE`, or `PRIVATE` to specify the scope or privacy of the directories. But a lot of antiquated code still uses [`include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html), and I'm not sure how these directories are treated by the targets that use them.

Is using `include_directories()` essentially the same as using `target_include_directories(MyTarget PRIVATE ...)`? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396608/what-is-default-target-link-libraries-privacy-setting/51404894) similar question, but is there no **default** scoping behavior with `include_directories()` either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is using `include_directories()` essentially the same as using `target_include_directories(MyTarget PRIVATE ...)`?

Yes, for every target, affected by `include_directories` (that is, in the current `CMakeLists.txt` and below), it has the **same effect** as `PRIVATE` keyword in target-specific version of the command.

---

[Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/include_directories.html) for `include_directories` says, that the command assigns `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of the targets and directories:

> The include directories are added to the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` directory property for the current `CMakeLists` file. They are also added to the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property for each target in the current `CMakeLists` file.

and the directory property [affects](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_dir/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) on further target's ones:

> This property is used to populate the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property.

Exactly `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property [is affected](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_include_directories.html) by the `PRIVATE` keyword of `target_include_directories` command:

> `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC` items will populate the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of `<target>`. `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` items will populate the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of `<target>`.