# Is it ok for CMake to use c++, rather than mpicxx, to compile my code?

Tags: c++, cmake, mpi, openmp, openmpi

I'm trying to build an executable from C++ source code which uses MPI, on a GNU/Linux Devuan Chimaera system. Now, I'm an MPI/OpenMP newbie, I'm just trying to adapt this code, which isn't mine, to be built with CMake - when before it had a `Makefile`. My build succeeds, but I'm seeing segfaults, so I want to make sure my problem isn't with the build phase, which bugs me.

My `CMakeLists.txt` has:

```
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
```

and my system has OpenMPI 4.1.1 installed, which is found. I do this for my target:

```
target_link_libraries(my_executable PRIVATE MPI::MPI_CXX OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

but nothing else which indicates its expecting to be compiled by mpicxx.

... and indeed, when I configure (with CMake 3.22.1) and then build, the usual `c++` executable gets invoked to compile (and then link) the `my_target` executable.

Questions:

- Can source code which originally was getting compiled with `mpicxx` be compiled with "just" a C++ compiler, with the appropriate includes?
- Assuming there's any merit to using `mpicxx` for compilation - how do I get CMake to use it for my target?

**Edit:** It's been suggested to me to try using `mpirun` to run my program. With it, I get no segmentation faults, consistently; it's only when I run directly that I see them.

Comment: You don't specify what `my_target` is, but if it's a library, those should probably be PUBLIC dependencies. "Default" privacy is tricky https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396608/what-is-default-target-link-libraries-privacy-setting#comment108374911_51404894

Comment: `mpicxx` is a shell script around the regular C++ compiler, with include and library paths set. So yes, if cmake can find those paths, you can use the base compiler.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Clarified that it's an executable - `my_executable`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout: I use OpenMPI 4.1.1, and there, `mpicxx` is _not_ a shell script. It's still kind of a wrapper, though. I think.

Comment: I've never used OpenMPI. Please explain? What *is* it?

Comment: I do this routinely on CrayPE systems that provide compiler wrappers. I've never needed to do more than link to `MPI::MPI_CXX` to make it work, there. However, in my case, this is explicitly supported by the vendor... https://docs.nersc.gov/development/build-tools/cmake/#mpi

Comment: `mpicxx` is a wrapper for the C++ compiler (it simply adds the include/library path and the MPI libraries at link time). This is indeed a binary by default with Open MPI (but you can make it a shell script by passing the `--enable-script-wrapper-compilers` option at `configure` time.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout: [This is OpenMPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_MPI).

Comment: @AlexReinking: It's an executable, so it doesn't matter all that much, but sure.

Answer (score 3):

> - Can source code which originally was getting compiled with mpicxx be compiled with "just" a C++ compiler, with the appropriate includes?

Yes, and you're doing it correctly.

The MPI systems I've used (Cori, Perlmutter, Stampede) have all provided implementations that work correctly with CMake's MPI support. However, it's possible that a sufficiently poorly administered system will break this.

> - Assuming there's any merit to using mpicxx for compilation - how do I get CMake to use it for my target?

This is a toolchain setting... set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to `/path/to/mpicxx` either at the command line, in a preset, or in a toolchain file.

Comment: But I can't have a different compiler for non-MPI and MPI C++ programs?

Comment: No, you cannot. CMake allows one compiler per language and doesn't consider MPI C++ to be distinct from non-MPI C++ (and it isn't... it's not like UPC++, say).

Comment: Are any of these MPI implementations FOSS?

Comment: So, I un-accepted this answer, because when I used the exact same command-lines as CMake was generating, but with the mpicxx wrapper, the linked program did not crash with a segmentation fault.