# pybind11 and another libs in one project

Tags: c++, cmake, pybind11

How I can make friends pybind11 with another libs? I using CMake and MinGW

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(cmake_example)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)

pybind11_add_module(cmake_example src/main.cpp)

target_compile_definitions(cmake_example PRIVATE VERSION_INFO=${EXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO})
```

This is default settings for getting start. I have another lib, which I build before. My attempt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(cmake_example)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
add_subdirectory(anotherlib_dir)

pybind11_add_module(cmake_example src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(anotherlib)

target_compile_definitions(cmake_example PRIVATE VERSION_INFO=${EXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO})
```

Where `anotherlib_dir` looks like this:

```
- lib
- src
- CMakeLists.txt
```

This lib works correctly (I tested it in clear project)

But this solution do not working. On building I have problems with `undefined reference`

Someone tried to make friends libraries? I don't know what else to try
I am sure that there are no problems with my library, since CMake defines it:
`The existing target is a static library created [cmake] in source directory ".../cmake_example".`

In clear project I link libs look like

```
add_subdirectory(anotherlib_dir)
target_link_libraries(ProjectName anotherlib)
```

In `pybind11` ProjectName not specified. As I understand, pybind11 has custom superctructure, which can define project.

Comment: Neither of your cmake lists define targets. Can't imagine they pass cmake configure steps successfully. `target_link_libraries(anotherlib)` also should raise an error.

Comment: Yes, it should. But on the contrary, it gives an [error](https://imgur.com/a/GzBW4Mz) if I specify a target.

Comment: @273K: "Neither of your cmake lists define targets."  - Actually, function `pybind11_add_module` creates a target.

Comment: @onyx1a: Concerning the error message on the screenshot which you posted as a comment, see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737558/uses-of-target-link-libraries-must-be-either-all-keyword-or-all-plain). Next time describe your attempts in the question post itself, and provide **textual** representation of the error: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors